# "minimumFetchInterval" is not defined in "RemoteConfigSettings"

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I wrote following code to use Firebase RemoteConfig feature.

```swift
let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
settings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
remoteConfig.configSettings = settings
```

However, following error was occurred.

```
Value of type 'RemoteConfigSettings' has no member 'minimumFetchInterval'
```

What is wrong ?

This code is the same in the Firebase official tutorial.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-ios?hl=en

Comment: Can I know the version of the `Firebase`?

Comment: I updated from v5.x to v6.x of Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I resolved this issue by myself.
I updated the Firebase remoteconfig version and it was resolved.